# how to make the custom repositories maven in Android studio appear in IDE project structure dependencies

Tags: maven, android-studio, gradle, ide, repository

I have a private maven server in google cloud.
in the main gradle I add the maven reference.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
       ...
       ...
        maven {
            credentials {
                username 'xxxx'
                password 'xxxx'
            }
            url "https://xxxxx-xxxxx-maven.appspot.com"
        }
    }
}
```

If I add the reference directly to the gradle of the app, it works perfectly.

```
compile'xxx.xxxx.xxxx:example:1.0'
OR
implementation 'xxx.xxxx.xxxx:example:1.0'
```

The problem is that the number of references is increasing, and if I try to use the option "Project Structure / Dependencies" it does not show me results when searching.

[image]

**How do I get my own private references to appear to me, to somehow take my credentials and show them?**

thanks